# c append char array to char array like in c++ and other higher languages

Tags: arrays, c, string

Im trying to append a string to a string like in other languages (for example +=).
I got it working that when not too much is added the string is correctly appened.
But when i tested the function it removed chars from the string.

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void append(char**str, char*append_str) {
    if(*str == NULL) *str = malloc(1);
    *str = realloc(*str, sizeof (*str)+strlen(append_str));
    sprintf(*str, "%s%s", *str, append_str);
}

int main() {

    char* base_str = NULL;
    append(&base_str, "hello dolly\n");
    append(&base_str, "dolly\n");
    append(&base_str, "dolly2\n");
    append(&base_str, "3dolly2\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        char* kv = NULL;
        char numberConv[5];
        sprintf(numberConv, "%d", i);
        append(&kv, numberConv);
        append(&kv, ":3dolly2\n");
        append(&base_str, kv);
        free(kv);
    }

    printf("%s\n", base_str);

    return 0;
}
```

The result. Here the the string loses characters after doll and 0:3dolly2. I dont know what causes that:

```
hello dolly
doll0:3dolly2
1:3dolly2
2:3dolly2
3:3dolly2
4:3dolly2
5:3dolly2
6:3dolly2
7:3dolly2
8:3dolly2
9:3dolly2
10:3dolly2
11:3dolly2
12:3dolly2
13:3dolly2
14:3dolly2
15:3dolly2
16:3dolly2
17:3dolly2
18:3dolly2
19:3dolly2
```

The expected result:

```
hello dolly
dolly
dolly2
3dolly2
0:3dolly2
1:3dolly2
2:3dolly2
3:3dolly2
4:3dolly2
5:3dolly2
6:3dolly2
7:3dolly2
8:3dolly2
9:3dolly2
10:3dolly2
11:3dolly2
12:3dolly2
13:3dolly2
14:3dolly2
15:3dolly2
16:3dolly2
17:3dolly2
18:3dolly2
19:3dolly2
```

Comment: You forgot to allocate room for the null terminator. Also use `strcat`, not `sprintf`.

Comment: And `sizeof(*str)` doesn't do what you probably think it does.  You'll need `strlen` there as well.

Comment: OT: `if(*str == NULL) *str = malloc(1);` is useless. You can remove this line altogether. `realloc(NULL, bar)` is the same as `malloc(bar)`.

Comment: Ok i have changed `sizeof(*str)` to `strlen(*str)` and added the `+1` for the null terminator. That change fixed the issue. When i remove `if(*str == NULL) *str = malloc(1);` i get an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS at line 14.